# How to hide imshow images and save the final image to a folder

Tags: matlab

How to get the `imshow` and `imshowpair` result as a .bmp image while hiding the `imshow` and `imshowpair`? Because I'm running my program in background which is integrated with another program. So i don't want to display the `imshow` result but I need to save that result to a folder.

```
figure(1);
imshowpair(registered,img2);
viscircles(centres,radii);
title('Registration','fontSize',12)

figure(2);
imshow(img2);
viscircles(centres,radii);
saveas(2,'Registered.bmp');
```

Comment: On Linux you can start MATLAB with the `-nodisplay` option. I'm not sure that works with Windows, but there is also a `-noFigureWindows` option there that you might want to try.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the figure visibility to false. E.g.

```
fig = figure('visible','off');
imshow(img)
saveas(fig,'img.png')
```